# "Method not found:'System.Text.Json.JsonEncodedText System.Text.Json.JsonEncodedText.Encode(System.String,System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder)

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk, azure-functions-core-tools

When I try to use Azure.Search.Documents in Azure function, there is a Json exception thrown.

**Environment summary** : VS Code, HttpTrigger Azure Function:V3, netcoreapp3.1

The Complete Stack trace for the same is :

"   at Azure.Search.Documents.Models.SearchResults`1.DeserializeAsync(Stream json, ObjectSerializer serializer, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Search.Documents.SearchClient.SearchInternal[T](SearchOptions options, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Search.Documents.SearchClient.SearchInternal[T](String searchText, SearchOptions options, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task)\r\n   at Azure.Search.Documents.SearchClient.Search[T](String searchText, SearchOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at SearchService.Utility.RunQueries(SearchClient srchclient, String inputVal, String gender, String body_part, String age_group)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a library mismatch in the azure function.  Installing the latest version of System.Text.Json makes sure the function will have the correct methods available.